# Как решить проблему переполнения стека в алгоритме быстрой сортировки?

Tags: java, сортировка

При запуске программа выдает ошибку переполнения стека. Метод разделения (part), судя по тестам, реализован правильно.

```
public class Main {
  
  public static void sort(int[] array) {
    qsort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
  }
  
  public static void qsort(int[] array, int li, int ri) {
    int dif = ri - li;
    if (dif < 1)
      return;
  
    int mid = (ri + li) / 2;
    int p = part(array, li, ri, mid);
    qsort(array, li, p - 1);
    qsort(array, p + 1, ri);
  }
  
  public static int part(int[] array, int li, int ri, int index) {
    swap(array, index, array.length - 1);
    index = ri - li;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = li; i < ri; i++)
      if (array[index] > array[i])
        swap(array, j++, i);
    swap(array, j, index);
    return j;
  }
  
  public static void swap(int[] array, int i1, int i2) {
    int temp = array[i1];
    array[i1] = array[i2];
    array[i2] = temp;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[] {5, 1, 8, 4, 6, 7, 3, 2, 2, 2};
    sort(arr);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Вызов `part(array, 1000, 1010, 1005)` приводит к обращению к элементу с номером 10 (`array[index]`, `index = ri - li`). Ошибка.

Comment: Очень рекомендую такие алгоритмы снабжать большим количеством утверждений для контроля: в данном случай упущены проверки, что `part` не обращается за пределы диапазона `[li, ri]`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо вам за отклик. Ошибка была из за моей невнимательности и любви после каждого второго утверждения компилировать программу. Исправленный метод part: ```public static int part(int[] array, int li, int ri, int index) {
    swap(array, index, ri);
    index = ri;
    int j = li;
    for (int i = li; i < ri; i++)
      if (array[index] > array[i])
        swap(array, j++, i);
    swap(array, j, index);
    return j;
  }```